# Should I minify and combine JS files for my PhoneGap app?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I understand the rationale behind minification etc. when the code is being downloaded by the browser, but in my PhoneGap app it'll be running locally. Is there any point in doing this if all the resources will be local?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you should still do the minification of the JS code. It won't help with network latency since the files are being loaded locally but minified code is parsed quicker by the browsers JavaScript engine. The quicker the JS is parsed the quicker your users get to use the app.

I would recommend waiting to minify the JS until the last step before your release your app because it is very difficult to debug minified code.

Comment: Do you have any benchmarks to support that? I'm interested to find out how much of a difference it makes.

Comment: I guess it would not hurt to minify it - but there are other opinions: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap_build_and_phonegap_js_compression -> In this phonegap forum post it is more about "the list of priorities for a PhoneGap application."

Comment: http://carlos.bueno.org/2010/02/measuring-javascript-parse-and-load.html#results under Minification FTW. Also there is a table in High Performance JavaScript by Zakas that shows the speed up in parse times of minified code.

Comment: @madflow Agreed it is not as important as it is on web site but it does help. Again, this would be the last thing I do when building my app.

Comment: Agreed. It does make a difference especially given that the processing power for mobile phone is much more limited. I minified my AngularJS app (900kb -> 150kb) and I do notice a significant performance increase (on iPhone 4S)